# Typescript infer keyword inferring wrong type?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

With a simple construct like this:

```
type Test<Source extends string[]> = 
    Source extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ? `${Head}${Head}` : never;
```

Typescript complains about the string interpolation inside `${Head}${Head}` saying: `` Type `'Head'` is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'. Type 'Head' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322) ``

...which does not make much sense to me but my searches did not turn fruitful. Source must be a `string[]` so `Head`, if it exists, must be a string right? So `${Head}` must be totally valid. Why is TS complaining about not being able to assign it to a `number`? String is also assignable to `"string | number | bigint | boolean"` so this error does not make much sense to me. I can fix it by putting the string interpolation between a `"Head extends string ? ... : ...` clause but I am wondering why it is necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.
Take a look on next example:

```js
type Test0<Source extends string[]> =
    Source extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ? Head : never;

type O = Test0<[never, 'a']> // no error, because that is how NEVER works
```

Because `string|never` returns `string`.

I think it is much safer to check if Head is string or not in above case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that TypeScript does not take the `extends string[]` constraint into account until after it has inferred the types. If you look at this type

```
type T<Head> = `${Head}`
```

you'll see the same rather obtuse error message (inference for template literals is a bit wonky). Since `T` does not infer `Head` here, you could of course just declare `type T<Head extends string> = ..`, but another option is to encode the `Head extends string` constraint in an extra conditional:

```
type T<Head> = Head extends string ? `${Head}` : never
```

This is why `Test` type checks if you add the extra, seemingly redundant, conditional:

```
type Test<Source extends string[]> = 
    Source extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] 
    ? Head extends string ? `${Head}${Head}` : never 
    : never;
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwA8BlA9gVwE4GNoQA9gIA7AE3ikSwEsSBzAbQF0A%20KAXigCgo%20p02PFELFylRnQBmELFAASEAIZkANFAB0W6bNhKaAG2Y9%20UAPwLlZEUVIUqwWg3NQABgBIA3opUBfLz5kvq5QAFxQJBAAbrq8-OGRMVgA3NzcoJCwAIxIgexcHt5WwdwA9KWw4NAA5IHVUDSUJGjAUErw8DT0JEoARgbQwGhQGTXUdPRQAD4RGAC2vbozvV10rctoaANKJNOzBgZ7GOQQUnQQZNUaZRUwVVC1VvWNES1tHV09-YPDow8k80WWCuaT%20MAATLkrDYxPZxgx8m4AsVXOl7jAAMxQlSIwIwuyUeGTCyFQLBMIRaKybhAA)